# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'cniEmetteur'

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to generate a pdf report with jasper ireport and java but I always have this exception :

**net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: cniEmetteur.**
...
...

**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'cniEmetteur'**

Here is a part of my jrxml file :

```
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="517"/>
<parameter name="idTrans" class="java.lang.String"/>

<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>

<field name="idTransaction" class="java.lang.Long"/>
<field name="code" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="commission" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="dateTransaction" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
<field name="emetteur" class="sn.groupeidyal.comparateur.persistence.Emetteur">

</field>
<field name="cniEmetteur" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="nomEmetteur" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="numTelEmetteur" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="prenomEmetteur" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="recepteur" class="sn.groupeidyal.comparateur.persistence.Recepteur">

</field>
<field name="cniRecepteur" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="nomDestinataire" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="numTelDestinataire" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="prenomDestinataire" class="java.lang.String"/>

<field name="montant" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="idPartenaire" class="java.lang.Long"/>
<field name="loginAgentEmetteur" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

...

Here is my Java code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    ArrayList<Transaction> ts = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    ts.add(new Transaction());
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ts);
    try {
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("recu.jrxml");
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("recu.jasper",
            null, beanCollectionDataSource);
        JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
        jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"C:\\recu.pdf");
    } catch (JRException ex) {
      }
}
```

My Entity transaction is here :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction implements Serializable {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_transaction")
    private Long idTransaction;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "date_transaction")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateTransaction;

    @Column(name = "login_agent_emetteur")
    private String loginAgentEmetteur;

    @Column(name = "montant")
    private Double montant;

    @Column(name = "commission")
    private Double commission;

    @Embedded
    private Emetteur emetteur;
    @Embedded
    private Recepteur recepteur;
}
```

In my class **Emetteur** I have field like cniEmetteur, nomEmetteur, prenomEmetteur, numTelEmetteur
and in **Recepteur** class I have nomDestinataire, prenomDestinataire, cniRecepteur and numTelDestinataire.

**I think that my problem is in my jrxml file. How to bind fields emetteur and cniEmetteur.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a field inside other field by using dot. Change `cniEmetteur` to `emetteur.cniEmetteur` and so on.